# Group multiple rows from one table?

Tags: database, database-design

I have a projects table with a many-to-many relationship with a images table through a junction table. I also want to add multiple cover images for a project.

I have multiple tables where I want to group some rows from the images table. Should I add a column with an boolean value if it's a cover image or should I create a one-to-many table with the ID's of the images I want as cover? And if I would add some column wouldn't it be redundant if most of the column values would be null?

There is also a clients and discipline table where I want to select images from the image table but add some extra columns like sortorder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both techniques have its merits and the answer can be opinion based; mine is. I'd recommend adding field (e.g. `cover`) to your images table indicating whether the image is primary or not to begin. It's okay for most rows to have NULL value in `cover` field. Create an index on imageid and cover.

I'd also recommend creating a view called CoverImages that would be `select ... from images where cover=true` so that whichever application needing only a cover image can directly use this view. Depending on your database engine, you may have the ability to create sparse columns and/or create filtered indexes.

The other option is to add `cover` to your junction table that has projectid and imageid. However, that would violate 2nd normal form of database normalization since `cover` would be an attribute of an image, not a project.

The option you mentioned - that of putting images that are cover images in one-to-many table - could be problematic when more flags are added. If the image is flagged as sensitive, you would then have to create another table and put only sensitive imageids in it.

Based on the last 2 thoughts, I recommend putting `cover` flag in images table.

**EDIT**

OP reminded that imageid 1 could be a cover for project1 but not for project2. That means `cover` should be associated with the junction table and not the images table. 2NF will not be violated

Comment: But a image could have multiple projects so I should add the cover column on the junction table for it to work.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are absolutely right, and you had mentioned that in your question; apologizes that I forgot about that when writing the answer. You'd, in that case, add `cover` to the junction table since that property is associated with both the project and the image - and won't violate 2nd normal form. Good point.